# Solve the following questions:

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Following are two questions and their respective answers(as given in textbook):

Q1. If $$ k=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{n \choose r}$$, then write $$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{r}{n \choose r}$$ in terms of k.

Ans. $$\frac {nk}{2}$$

Q2. If $$x+y=1$$ find $$\sum_{r=0}^n r^{2} y^{n-r} x^r$$.

Ans. $$n(nx+y)$$

The thing is, I have tried solving both the problems, but that hasn't been much fruitful.
I faced difficulties from the first one as the expressions are sum of reciprocals of binomial coefficients. Because I never came across such reciprocals earlier.
The problem with the second is because of the two terms x and y. Had either x or y not been there, I could have easily differentiated $$ (1+x)^n$$ or $$ (1+y)^n$$ and their respective expansions and derived the result.

So, I would be thankful to anyone who provides a proper solution for each of the above problems.
Note: I wanted to add 'homework' tag, but wasn't allowed to do so.

Comment: Is there an exponent missing in the answer to the second problem? Because in the way it stands there it is wrong.

Comment: The answers i've mentioned are the ones given in the textbook. There are possibilities of errors. So it'd be helpful if you write the solution you've got as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first problem, 
$$k=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{n \choose r}$$
=$$\frac{1}{n \choose 0}+\frac{1}{n \choose 1}+..\frac{1}{n \choose n}$$
Now, $$ {n\choose r} = {n\choose n-r}$$
(I can now make pairs of two terms taking the first term from the beginning and last term as my first pair, I can add them directly as their denominators are the same)
$$\implies k= \frac{2}{n \choose 0}+\frac{2}{n \choose 1}+\cdots$$
hence $$\frac{k}{2}=\frac{1}{n \choose 0}+\frac{1}{n \choose 1}+\cdots$$
(I'm not worried whether n is odd or even here, as you will see later that I have no interest in evaluating this sum)

Consider 
$$l=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{r}{n \choose r}$$
$$\implies l=\frac{0}{n \choose 0}+\frac{1}{n \choose 1}+\frac{2}{n \choose 2}+\cdots +\frac{n-2}{n \choose n-2}+\frac{n-1}{n \choose n-1}+\frac{n}{n \choose n}$$
(Again I pair the terms the way I had done previously) 
$$\implies l=\frac{n}{n \choose 0}+\frac{n}{n \choose 1}+\cdots$$
$$\implies l=\frac{nk}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you. Any idea for the second one? If yes do you think the answer I wrote is missing an exponent (as informed by @frog) ?

Comment: What I mean is that the formula as it stands cannot be true (it suffices to check the case $n=1$). But I looked at your expression for a while and I cannot come up with a closed form (which is what you are looking for, right?)... Is there any context to that exercise?

Comment: Yes frog is right, there is some error in the second question

Comment: And @nikunj, don't you think its important to show, seperately, what happens when the expansion has even and odd number of terms?.. e.g. when there are odd terms, the $$(\frac{n}{2}+2)^{th}$$ term can't find another term with a similar denominator.. I know the answer is still the same as I've now found myself but i think showing it explicitly is not trivial to the solution..

Comment: @Phill2 see if n is odd, then the series will contain the term that you say and it won't have another pair, but that isn't important for us because we use the exact same series regardless of n being even or odd, so even if it didn't manage to find a pair, (i.e n was odd) we just substitute the whole series. We would have cared about it if we had to evaluate that summation, which we do not need.

Comment: Ah. Alright.. but keeping an odd term feels odd (hence the name).. Since you are taking out 2 from the entire series and yet there is a term alone with no 2.. I'd rather prefer to mention it.. Plus a typing error in my previous comment led me to write (n/2+2) which should've been (n/2+1)

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, start with:

$\begin{align}
   \sum_{0 \le r \le n} x^r y^{n - r}
     &= y^n \sum_{0 \le r \le n} \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^r \\
     &= y^n \frac{1 - (x/y)^{n + 1}}{1 - x/y} \\
     &= \frac{y^{n + 1} - x^{n + 1}}{y - x} \\
   x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}
     \left(
       x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}
           \frac{y^{n + 1} - x^{n + 1}}{y - x}
     \right)
     &= \sum_{0 \le r \le n} r^2 x^r y^{n - r} 
\end{align}$

The result is a quite ugly expression:

$\begin{align}
   &\frac{y^n (x^2 y + x y^2) 
           - (n + 1)^2 x^{n + 1} y^2
           + (2 n^2 + 2 n - 1) x^{n + 2} y 
           - n^2 x^{n + 3}}
        {(y - x)^3} \\
    &\qquad = \frac{y^{n + 1} x (x + y)
                     - x^{n + 1} 
                        ((n^2 + 2 n + 1) y^2
                          - (2 n^2 + 2 n - 1) x y
                          + n^2 x^2)}
                    {(y - x)^3} \\
    &\qquad = \frac{y^{n + 1} x (x + y)
                     - x^{n + 1} (y - x)
                         ((n + 1)^2 y - n^2 x)
                    }
                    {(y - x)^3} \\
    &\qquad = \frac{y^{n + 1} x
                     - x^{n + 1} (y - x)
                         ((n + 1)^2 y - n^2 x)
                    }
                    {(y - x)^3}
\end{align}$

Yes, it is fine to consider $x$ and $y$ as separate variables, as mentioned. The relation $x + y = 1$ can be used to simplify the end result, however.